# If $P$ is an interior point of triangle $ABC$, prove $\frac{AF}{FB} + \frac{AE}{EC} = \frac{AP}{PD} $

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, ratio

> **QUESTION:** Let $P$ be an interior point of the $\Delta ABC$. Assume that $AP$, $BP$ , $CP$ meet the opposite sides $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ at $D$ , $E$ and $F$ respectively. Prove that
>
> $$\frac{AF}{FB} + \frac{AE}{EC} = \frac{AP}{PD} $$

At first I tried to use the concept of similarity of triangles but that didn't help. Then, I thought about assigning some coordinates to the vertices (since that still confides the generality of the problem), but there are too many variables arising out of it.. so I had to bunk that idea as well.. I am just a high school student and do not have extensive knowledge when it comes to geometry..

How can I prove something with not one information given?
Can anyone please help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your last few posts provided decent contexts and efforts. Why did you fail to do so on this one?

Comment: You mean the probability one?

Answer (score 0):

Let [] denote areas. Then,

\begin{align}
\frac{AP}{PD} &= \frac{[ABE]}{[DBE]}
= \frac{\frac{AE}{AC}[ABC] }{ \frac{BD}{BC}\frac{EC}{AC}[ABC]  }  
= \frac{AE(BD+DC)}{EC \cdot BD }  \\
&= \frac{AE}{EC } + \frac{AE}{EC }  \frac{DC}{BD } 
= \frac{AE}{EC } + \frac{AF}{FB }  \end{align}

where the Ceva’s theorem  $\frac{AE}{EC }  \frac{DC}{BD } \frac{BF}{FA }=1 $ is used in the last step.

Comment: Can you please explain the first step once.. how did you do $\frac{AP}{PD} = \frac{ABE}{DBE} $ ?

Comment: @Stranger Forever - because the two triangles share the same base BE and the ratio of their heights is proportional to AP/PD

Comment: Oh I get it.. but I did not understand how you wrote $DBE$ to be $\frac{EC}{AC} \frac{BD}{BC} ABC$ . Does that come from the same concept?

Comment: @StrangerForever - same concept $[DBE ]= \frac{BD}{BC}[BEC]  =  \frac{BD}{BC}\frac{EC}{AC}[ABC]$

Comment: Oh I get it now.. thank you so much..

Comment: How is $ AP/PD = Ar(ABE)/Ar( BDE).$ $BDE $ is not even a triangle. I think you meant $AP/PD = Ar(ABP)/Ar( BDP)?$ @quanto